# Update query increment field plus 1 codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I got a problem when trying to increment by 1 on given field in my db. I tried with and without active records.

My functions look like this (in my model)

```
function _set_reads($id){
$this->db->set('reads', 'reads+1', FALSE)
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('article');
}
```

and

```
function _set_reads($id){
$sql = 'update article set reads=reads+1 where id=?';
$this->db->query($sql, array($id));
}
```

I get the same error in both cases and it's the following error message:

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'reads+1 WHERE `id` = '15'' at line 1

UPDATE `article` SET `reads` = reads+1 WHERE `id` = '15'
```

I am using the latest version of MAMP

Answer (score 13):

-- Need small correction

```
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->set('set_row', '`set_row`+ 1', FALSE);
```

Thank You

Answer (score 7):

Solved it: 
I had to change

```
$this->db->set('reads', 'reads+1', FALSE)
```

to

```
$this->db->set('reads', '`reads+1`', FALSE)
```

Sorry for the post...

Comment: why to prevent the value from being escaped ?

Comment: ```$this->db->set('reads', '`reads+1`', FALSE)``` must be ```$this->db->set('reads', '`reads`+1', FALSE)```

Comment: How can i do it with `update_batch()` multiple records have different value to increment?

Comment: @Jitendra did you ever get a solution to your question?

Comment: @owsata, i am really sorry. i don't remember now that. Ofcourse i did some solution for that but i don't remember as of now.

Answer (score 3):

**[set()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html)** will also accept an optional third parameter `($escape)`, that will prevent data from being escaped if set to `FALSE`.